# Power in uniform circular motion

Tags: energy-conservation, orbital-motion, power

Say you have a rocket ship in a vacuum away from all gravitational fields firing its engines to maintain uniform circular motion. Since the engines are burning fuel, it seems to make sense to calculate the power output in watts. But the Force in the direction of the Velocity is zero so the power is zero. I'm confused. And since the Kinetic energy is not increasing, where does the energy expended by the engine go?

Comment: Into the kinetic energy of the exhaust gases. it's basically the same as rocket was hovering in a gravitational field.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to rephrase. Given all else, can the energy provided by the engine that is required to maintain the path be computed?

Comment: I found an answer that applies : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171748/how-much-power-does-it-take-to-keep-a-massive-particle-suspended-in-a-gravitatio?rq=1